# how to export a complete database in DB2 and Import it in another PC?

Tags: database, db2

I Gave a Brief look at the DB2LOOK command @
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0002051.html

and about db2move command.

But I am still not sure how it works as I am new to DB2.

Can this be done in any easier way?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you don't change platforms or skip over DB2 versions (e.g. only moving from one Windows machine to another) you can use backup and (possibly redirected) restore.

Comment: can You suggest me some links where I can have a WalkThrough

Comment: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.ha.doc/doc/c0006150.html, http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.ha.doc/doc/c0006237.html